# Confusion regarding Ampère's law and non-planar loops

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

To show that  $\int_{C} \vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl}=4\pi I/c$ for this loop

[image]

Purcell uses this other path ($C'$)

[image: ![enter image description here]

He argues that since $C'$ doesn't enclose the wire

$$\begin{align*}\int_{C'}\vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl'}&=0\\
\int_{C_1}\vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl_1}+\int_{C}\vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl}&=0\end{align*}$$

and since $\int_{C_1}\vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl_1}=-4\pi I/c$ then
$$\int_{C}\vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl}=4\pi I/c.$$

But I might as well choose to add another circular loop like $C_2$ (assuming $C$ is non planar). Now in this case I would get
$$\int_{C}\vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl}=\color{red}{2}\times 4\pi I/c=8\pi I/c$$

[image]

Here, $C_2$ is in front of $C_1$. Where does this contradiction arise from?

Comment: Why is C2 non-planar? and why do you think there is a contradiction? Are the other current loops in the same plane?

Comment: There is only one wire and it's represented by the dot(the wire is coming at us out of the screen). The loops $C$, $C_1$, $C$ and $C'$ are not wires.

Comment: sorry, I meant paths, not current loops.

Comment: 1) I didn't say $C_2$ was non planar, it is planar: it is within the plane that's perpendicular to the wire. 2) The contradiction is that we get two different values of the line integral of $B$ around $C$.

Comment: Ok, still though, why does it matter that C is non-planar regarding your choice of C2? And the magnetic field wouldn't be parallel to the path element for your choice of C2, would that change the integral?

Comment: If $C$ was planar, $C_1$ and $C_2$ would cross each other.

Comment: I see, but now it looks like your integral around C' being equal to zero isn't correct as the entire path including C2 does enclose the wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that you pulled and reshaped the part of the loop you called $C1$ as shown below.

[image]

In doing this you have not cut through the current carrying conductor.

You can now see that within your Amperian loop you have the current carrying conductor.